# Почему моя функция удаления подстроки выводит неверный результат?

Tags: c++, c, строки

Функция должна удалять подстроку из строки , начало и конец включительно , подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка , при строчке 1234567890 выводит 1234

```cpp
char* strdel1(char* str, int p, int k) 
{
    if ((p <= 0) || (k < 0)) 
        return str;
    int size = strlen(str);
    if (k >= size) 
        return str;
    if(k+p >= size)
    {
        str[k] = 0;
        return str;
    }
    for (int i = k-1; i < size-k-2; i++)
    {
        str[size - k - 2] = str[k]; 
        k++;
    }
    str[size - k] = 0;
    return str;
}
```

Функция при вводе строки 1234567890,3,6(3 и 6 это начало и конец) выводит строчку 1234 ,а должна выводить 127890. Функция должна удалять включительно слева и справа
p -начальная позиция , k- конечная

Исправил код:

```cpp
if ((p <= 0) || (k < 0)) return str;
    int size = strlen1(str);
    if (k > size) return str;
    //if(k+p >=size)
    //{
    //  str[k] = 0;
    //  return str;
    //}
    for (int i = k; i < size-1; i++)
    {
        str[i-p-1] = str[i];
    }
    //str[k] = 0;
    return str;
```

Comment: А насчёт ответа, Вы `p` толком нигде не используете в преобразовании строки. Только в проверках. А если я вангую верно и это позиция первого элемента подстроки, то использовать её крайне желательно.

Comment: Первый и второй `if` я могу понять. А вот третий... То есть если мне нужно взять подстроку между 7ым и 9ым символом в строке, где символов 10, то мне вернётся строка до 9ого символа? Явно что-то не то.

Comment: этот if можно убрать , не нужный

Comment: у меня цикл for неправильный

Comment: пока не понимаю где ошибка

Comment: Ошибка, как минимум, в том, что Вы `p` там не используете.

Comment: Постарайтесь хотя бы сами себе объяснить, что делают обе строки этого цикла, зачем они там.

Comment: Посмотрите сами на свой код внимательно. Хотя бы вот на это: `str[k-p-1] = str[i];` Вы `k` и `p` нигде не меняете. То есть `str[k-p-1]` – это постоянно один и тот же символ. И вы ему поочерёдно присваиваете разные значения. Смысл??

Comment: я теперь вместо k поставил счетчик i, строчка никак не меняется

Comment: Просто поменять счётчик недостаточно. Напишите код так, чтобы Вы сами могли объяснить **хотя бы себе**, что делает каждая строка. Не пишите наобум. Подумайте.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
char* strdel1(char* str, int p, int k) 
{
    if (p <= 0 || k < p ) return str;
    if (k > strlen(str)) k = strlen(str);
    while(str[p++ -1] = str[k++]);
    return str;
}
```

Только учтите, что вы почему-то нумеруете символы в строке, начиная с 1, в то время как в С/С++ принята нумерация с 0. Но, хозяин-барин, сделал по вашему заказу :)

Comment: Хорошо , я исправил вроде , но в чем здесь ошибка                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                       ```char* strdel1(char* str, int p, int k) {
 if ((p <= 0) || (k < 0)) return str;
 int size = strlen1(str);
 if (k > size) return str;
 //if(k+p >=size)
 //{
 // str[k] = 0;
 // return str;
 //}
 for (int i = k; i < size-1; i++)
 {
  str[k-p-1] = str[i];
 }
 //str[k] = 0;
 return str;```

Comment: @Harry, крашится на цикле при `strdel1("1234568790", 7, 9)`

Comment: @МаратГумеров, добавляйте вопросы по коду в вопрос, пожалуйста. В комментариях это абсолютно нечитаемо

Comment: странно , у меня просто никаких изменений в строке не происходит

Comment: @V-Mor https://ideone.com/aJpxBe А у вас крашится потому что - **какой тип передавать надо**? `char*` А что передаете вы? `const char[]` - вас это не наталкивает на грустные мысли, что, например, не надо на велосипед взваливать пару тонн груза? Что все надо использовать **по назначению**? `const` видите?

Comment: @Harry, понял. Да, действительно, сглупил.

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж вопрос (даже до моей правки) звучал как "**почему** не работает?", я постараюсь расписать причины:

1. Третья проверка (`if(k+p >= size)` и т.д.). Здесь зачем-то проверяется сумма позиций на предмет выхода за длину строки. Но ведь я преспокойно могу взять подстроку между 7ым и 9ым символом строки, содержащей 10 символов. А эта функция в таком случае вернёт мне символы с 0ого по 6ой... Явно что-то не то.
2. Далее цикл... Сложно сказать, что именно там неверно, т.к. мне абсолютно не ясна задумка автора, но я всё же попробую:

Представьте, что `k` у Вас равен 9 в той же самой стоке из 10 символов. Что происходит в цикле: Вы начинаете цикл с `i = 8` и продолжаете, пока `i` не станет `10 - 9 - 2 = -1`. При этом наращиваете `i` (`i++`). Как Вы думаете, станет ли когда-нибудь `i` равно `-1`, если Вы каждый раз прибавляете к нему 1, а изначально оно было равно `8`? На самом деле, конечно, станет, но это уже другая история. Проблема здесь в том, что логика очень и очень хромает.

Я мог бы продолжить свои разглагольствования о том, почему данный код не работает, но сдаётся мне, что, т.к. [@Harry](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195342/harry) уже предложил как реализовать то же самое гораздо проще, необходимость в этом отпадает.